# In espresso, how can I test that textview shows only two lines

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a TextView which has the following text: `"line1.\nline2.\n line3"`.
I set the TextView to be ellipsized at the end and limit to maximum two lines. To test that it shows ellipses, I have this code

```
public static final String TEST_BODY = "line1.\nline2.\nline3.";
//a setup method is called so that mail_cell_body_preview_field is set to above TEST_BODY
//...  

public void testMessageSnippetIsVisible() {
    onView(withId(R.id.mail_cell_body_preview_field)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.mail_cell_body_preview_field)).check(matches(hasEllipsizedText()));
    onView(withId(R.id.mail_cell_body_preview_field)).check(matches(withText(TEST_BODY)));
    //Add statement to verify that line3 not visible in UI           
}
```

How can I write a test case to verify that in UI, the third line is not visible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote that matcher to check lines count:

```
public static TypeSafeMatcher<View> isTextInLines(final int lines) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
            return ((TextView) item).getLineCount() == lines;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("isTextInLines");
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.activity_main_text_tv))
            .check(matches(CustomMatchers.isTextInLines(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onView(withId(R.id.mail_cell_body_preview_field)).check(matches( ......compare length for this...);
```

Use text comparison with your text length. like if you have 2 lines then text length is more.

Comment: The view has the full text underneath. Its only in the UI that it shows 
`line1
lin...`
How can I test on text length?

Comment: share full code you write to match something na ?then use that text to get length. & prededfine text length. or you can put something like if I have more than 20 chars. in one line 21 char will be in next line.
share full code & text you want to compare

Comment: You cann't compare strings lines as this ways. As esspro dont have any api for this. You need to compare texts.
Or you can compare two images by using monkeytalk