# How to assert multi line text in TextView in Kotlin test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, android-espresso

I have an `EditText` element in which an arbitrary text is allowed to be entered in. After the text has been entered, the user can click next and move to an activity that has the text they wrote inside a read-only `TextView`.

I'm trying to write a unit test that asserts that whatever the user writes in the first activity is correctly passed to the second. My trouble is that when I try to enter a multi-line text in the test e.g.

```
val textToPass = "This is a\nmulti line\nstring."
// or
val textToPass = """
This is a
multi line
string
""".trimIndent()
```

and I assert via

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.my_text_label))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.withText("Text: $textToPass")))
```

I get an assertion error that `Text: This is a\nmulti line\nstring.` does not equal `Text: This is amulti linestring.`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1)assert that the text is: "This is amulti linestring."

And then

2)assert that there are 3 lines in the `TextView`.

for the second assertion you can use the solution described in the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296194/16210149

Comment: The `lineCount` keeps coming back as one so `return ((TextView) item).getLineCount() == lines;` always returns false.

Comment: But what do you see in the TextView during test, there are really 3 lines?

Comment: The test used to say `This is a\nmulti line\nstring does not equal This is amulti linestring` as mentioned in the question. With the method you suggested I now get this `'isTextInLines' doesn't match the selected view.` although I used it the same way as it is used in the question linked. Placing a breakpoint shows that `lineCount` is 1 anyway. As in, the function understands the filtered single line version `This is amulti linestring`